# Retrieving default product image in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've been looking all over google and Stackoverflow but can't seem to find the solution.

I'm a beginner in magento and need to display default photo image on a product page when there are no images entered for that specific product.

Is there a function or something that could help me?

Comment: Does the default image exist..?

Answer (score 3):

In Admin side

Go to

System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to change anything to allow a default image to show, just don't enter an image.

If you need to change that default image, follow Pradeep's advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default placeholder picture in:

```
System->Configuration->Catalog->Product image placeholders
```